# zend docroot does not change

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, zend-framework

Just now I have start with zend framework, I have succesfully install zend framework, I followed the  [quick start guide](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) I am stuck with doc root.

**Short description of what I have done**

1) Install lamp and zend framework

2) cd /var/www

3) zf create project quickstart

4) cd quickstart/library/

5) ln -s /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend .

6) vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zend.gworks.mobi
    DocumentRoot /var/www/quickstart/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /var/www/quickstart/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

note: also I tried with **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** but no luck

7) service apache2 restart

But still my browser point **/var/www/html/index.html** not **/var/www/quickstart/public/index.php**, I'm out of ideas. can anyone help me what I miss?

---

### Solution (update)

I did right. when I restart vagrant, document root problem got solved, I don't know why it is not work previosly. but it throws `.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'` then I run this command `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart` now it shows zend framework welcome page

Comment: Adding `Solved` to a title is not how Stack Overflow works. Post your solution as a proper answer.

Comment: I am not convinced myself to post this is an answer because my question have no mistakes that is why I intimate in my question itself for future reader. If you feel it is wrong, I will post an answer.

Comment: But *it solved your problem*! At the least, remove that "Solved" from your title. If you have questions about your own solution, you should edit that into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit /etc/hosts file and add below line then do apache2 restart..

> 127.0.0.1 zend.gworks.mobi

Comment: yup already I did these two `127.0.0.1 zend.gworks.mobi` `192.168.1.30 zend.gworks.mobi` but it does not work

Comment: problem got solved, I update answer in my question itself. thanks  @himesh